# CAShapelayer Duplicates

Tags: swift, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to add a CAShapelayer once every 20ms to given x and y coordinates. I would like the shape to fade away over a second (like a tracer). The function I have created works, the shape is created in the correct location and fades away. But I am getting extra shapes left behind cluttering up the screen.

```
func shadowBall (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat){

    let xpos : CGFloat = ((self.frame.width/2) + x)
    let ypos : CGFloat = ((self.frame.height/2) + y)

    let shadowBall = CAShapeLayer()
    let shadowBalllRadius :CGFloat = 4
    let shadowBallPath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: xpos, y: ypos, width: CGFloat(shadowBalllRadius*2), height: CGFloat(shadowBalllRadius*2)))

    shadowBall.path = shadowBallPath.CGPath
    shadowBall.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shadowBall.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    shadowBall.lineWidth = 0.5

    let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeColor")
    animation.fromValue = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    animation.toValue = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    animation.duration = 1.0;
    animation.repeatCount = 0;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = true
    animation.additive = false

    self.layer.addSublayer(shadowBall)
    shadowBall.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "strokeColor")

}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I find the "every 20ms" to be curiously close (but not equal to) the max frame rate of 60 fps. Are you using `NSTimer` for that? Why not use a `CADisplayLink`, which is essentially a timer optimized for frame updates?

Comment: I have a BLE device with a refresh frequency max of 50Hz ... hence 20ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the animation finishes, it restores the `strokeColor` to the original color. You should really set the `strokeColor` of the original shape layer to be `clearColor()`, that way, when you finish animating from `whiteColor()` to `clearColor()`, it will remain at `clearColor()`.

You can also set the layer's `fillMode` to `kCAFillModeForwards` and set `removedOnCompletion` to `false` and that will have the layer preserve its "end of animation" state. But I personally would just set the `strokeColor` as outlined above, as using `removedOnCompletion` of `true` interferes with `animationDidStop` (see below).

---

Also, I might suggest that you also remove the layer once it's done with the animation so it doesn't continue to consume memory although it's no longer visible.

```
func shadowBall (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
    let xpos: CGFloat = ((self.frame.width/2) + x)
    let ypos: CGFloat = ((self.frame.height/2) + y)

    let shadowBall = CAShapeLayer()
    let shadowBalllRadius: CGFloat = 4
    let shadowBallPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: xpos, y: ypos, width: CGFloat(shadowBalllRadius*2), height: CGFloat(shadowBalllRadius*2)))

    shadowBall.path = shadowBallPath.CGPath
    shadowBall.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shadowBall.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shadowBall.lineWidth = 0.1

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeColor")
    animation.fromValue = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    animation.toValue = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    animation.duration = 1.0
    animation.repeatCount = 0
    animation.removedOnCompletion = true
    animation.additive = false

    animation.delegate = self
    animation.setValue(shadowBall, forKey: "animationLayer")

    self.layer.addSublayer(shadowBall)
    shadowBall.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "strokeColor")
}

override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    if let layer = anim.valueForKey("animationLayer") as? CALayer {
        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```

See [How to remove a CALayer-object from animationDidStop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6330701/1271826)

Comment: Brilliant and simple, thanks for the quick reply. Been bugging me for a while this issue...